# How to return a POJO from room query

Tags: android, android-room

I have a Room Query , which returns few fields of the `POJO`. Eg. query returns `group_id`, `group_name` only But the `POJO` have more fields like 
`sender_name`, message etc. If I compile the code it gives me an error. I see my build getting failed, But no error related to `ROOM`.

I want to know can I have more fields in `POJO` than what the query returns. Because if I keep only `group_Id` and `group_name` in `POJO`, compilation succeeds.

```
@Query("SELECT group_id,group_name FROM group")
fun getGroups(): DataSource.Factory<Int, Chat>

    class Chat {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
    var groupId: String = ""

    @ColumnInfo(name = "group_name")
    var groupName: String? = null

    var sender: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "created_by")
    var createdBy: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
    var messageId: String? = null

    @ColumnInfo(name = "message")
    var text: String? = null
}
```

Comment: 1.put `Cursor` as return type and iterator.
or
2. Write Query like this `SELECT * FROM group` and set `List<Chat>` as return type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate your POJO class as `(Optional)`,

```
@Entity(tableName = "group")
class Chat {

@ColumnInfo(name = "group_id")
var groupId: String = ""

@ColumnInfo(name = "group_name")
var groupName: String? = null

var sender: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "created_by")
var createdBy: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "message_id")
var messageId: String? = null

@ColumnInfo(name = "message")
var text: String? = null
}
```

and change your return type as,

```
@Query("SELECT group_id,group_name FROM group")
fun getGroups(): List<Chat>
```

(this might remove your compilation error).

Comment: the `@Entity` might need a `tableName`.